# Angular JS function to reset variables in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and wanted to create a function getting called if a Button has pressed to reset some check-boxes, input fields and select fields. I tried the following:

My JS-File:

```
Module.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.checkbox= false;
    $scope.textfield = "";
    $scope.selectfield= "-1";

    $scope.reset = function(){
      $scope.checkbox= false;
      $scope.textfield = "";
      $scope.selectfield= "-1";
}
});
```

My HTML-snippet:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox">
<select ng-model="selectfield">
   <option value="-1">undefined</option>
   <option value="0">Level 0</option>
   <option value="1">Level 1</option>
   <option value="2">Level 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" ng-model="textfield">
<button ng-click="reset()">Reset Filter</button>
```

But running this does not update the value inside the HTML. I do not understand why. Any Ideas?

EDIT:

I have also put in some alert boxes in my code and found out that toggling a check-box for example does work but setting its value to false does have no effect. The function is getting called and Module and Controller are assigned correctly. Here my code for toggling check-box which is working:

```
$scope.toggle = function(){
    $scope.checkbox = !$scope.checkbox;
}
```

Why is this working and updating the value correctly but setting it directly to false is not working???

I have found out that the value of my check-box does not change if i click it. There is a check mark displayed but the value of $scope.checkbox = false.

Comment: Changing the value of e.g. `textfield` works? Any errors, warnings?

Comment: Your code works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/r9o2f7mj/

Comment: Have you assigned ng-controller="FirstCtrl" in your Body element?

Comment: I was trying to figure out the same thing @jbrown is suggesting. Maybe you didn't define the controller in your html

Comment: @jbrown Yes I defined the controller inside a div element above the check-box, textfield, select-box and reset-button.

Answer (score 3):

It is working as charm, without changes - probably you have got issue somewhere else.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.checkbox = false;
    $scope.textfield = "";
    $scope.selectfield = "undefined";

    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.checkbox = false;
      $scope.textfield = "";
      $scope.selectfield = "undefined";
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox">
    <select ng-model="selectfield">
      <option value="-1">undefined</option>
      <option value="0">Level 0</option>
      <option value="1">Level 1</option>
      <option value="2">Level 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="textfield">
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset Filter</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$scope.selectfield = "-1"` instead of `$scope.selectfield = "undefined";`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f4mbq3as/ It says `$scope.selectfield` is undefined after you click reset

Comment: I don't know authors intence - why there is `"undefined"` as string assigned to `selectfield`

Comment: @Hadi Sorry that was a mistake just in this question in code i have written "-1". I have corrected it. Its not working for all of these three (no check-box, textfield or select-box reset).